# How do I extract a specific column from a dataset using pandas that's imported from a HTML file?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Importing html
df = pd.read_html(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/HTMLSpider/HTMLSpider_test/spotgamma.html"))
print (df['Latest Data'])
```

All of the documentation I can find online states that extracting a specific column from a dataset required you to specify the name of the column header in square braces, yet this is returning a TypeError when I try to do so:

```
>
    print (df['Latest Data'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

If you're curious as to what the dataset looks like without trying to specify the column:

```
     SpotGamma Proprietary Levels Latest Data  ...    NDX    QQQ
0                        Ref Price:        4465  ...  15283    372
1        SpotGamma Imp. 1 Day Move:      0.91%,  ...    NaN    NaN
2        SpotGamma Imp. 5 Day Move:       2.11%  ...    NaN    NaN
3           SpotGamma Gamma Index™:        0.48  ...   0.04  -0.08
4              Volatility Trigger™:        4415  ...  15075    373
5  SpotGamma Absolute Gamma Strike:        4450  ...  15500    370
6               Gamma Notional(MM):        $157  ...     $4  $-397
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

```
df = pd.read_html(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/HTMLSpider/HTMLSpider_test/spotgamma.html"))
```

will return a **list of** dataframes, not a single one.

See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html ("Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.")

Better do

```
ldf = pd.read_html(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/HTMLSpider/HTMLSpider_test/spotgamma.html"))
```

and then

```
df = ldf[0]  # replace 0 with the number of the dataframe you want
```

to get the first dataframe (there may be more, check `len(ldf)` to see how many you got and which one has the column you need).

Comment: If it does, (since you're new) please mark this "solved"

Comment: There's a cooldown before I'm able to mark it as solved, I'm just waiting for that to run out.